# R-Pi as Access Point - How can I extend the wifi range?

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm running my R-Pi as an IoT server at the office, where it connects to the internet modem both via LAN and WiFi (just to be sure it'll work no matter what) on the network 192.168.0.0, and it connects to the IoT stations (ESP8266s) via WiFi (the R-Pi acts as an AP using a virtual interface, as discused [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=138730)) using network 10.0.0.0. Everything works fine and we're all happy at the office, but now we need to install this system on the whole building, and clearly the R-Pi as AP is not powerfull enough. So we want to use the building's APs to extend this network, but I haven't the faintest idea how to do it.

So the question would be, how can I extend the range of the network generated by a R-Pi as AP using aditional APs? We're using D-Link APs managed by a CWM server.

Comment: BTW, it's a R-Pi 3

Comment: rather than duplicating things, connect your pi and the ESPs to the existing network, and either get your network admins to give the pi a fixed IP or use name resolution on the ESPs to find the pi on the network. otherwise you would need a network of repeaters for a building that apparently already has network coverage

Comment: @JamesKent Actually That's exactly what I want, to use the existing infraestructure as a network of repeaters. I don't want to connect the ESPs to the "public" network for some reasons. 1) There's a lot of them, and they would consume the network IPs. 2) I'd have to reprogram each of them. 3) Anyone would be able to access them, so it's a security concern. That's why they're connecting to a private hidden network.

Comment: Sharing the infrastructure but keeping the usage separate would be possible with VLan tagging, but I don't know if the ESP8266 will fit in there and if your current equipment will support that.

Comment: without knowing what the infrastructure you have is it's impossible for anyone to tell you how to do this. in essence it sounds like you want each AP to broadcast 2 SSIDs, the normal network one and a hidden ESP only one, that is hardware specific and nothing to do with the ESP or the Pi. and then you'd need to route the hidden SSID to a VLAN to keep them separate on the network.

Comment: what might be more appropriate would be to assign ESP devices (using a MAC filter) IP addresses on a different subrange to the rest of the network. then as long as your subnet mask is restrictive enough your normal network would not be able to "see" the ESPs and vice versa. not that this is not completely secure, as anyone who could change their network settings would be able to access them. otherwise you'll need to spend some money on a second set of repeaters to create a second network

Comment: I'll give it a try to VLANs. Yes, the infrastructure is able to manage multiple SSIDs and VLANs, it's based on D-Links DAP 2660 APs and a server running CWM to manage them. I'll change the Pi from AP to client to simplify the config. Thanks for your comments ;)